# Bind Raphael object to existing dom element

Tags: raphael

I have DOM element that is used by morris.js in order to create chart.

```
<div id="line-example"></div>
```

After chart is processed and rendered I want to use same svg element to add things to chart that are not supported by library. I tried the following:

```
var div = $('#line-example');
var paper = Raphael(div.find('svg'), div.width(), div.height());
```

but it creates brand new svg element

Comment: I think just use div, rather than find('svg'). Raph uses a div (Snap uses an svg) iirc.

Answer (score 1):

Better is to go simple: Remove Old Chart & Add New chart.
Markup:

```
<div id="someID"></div>
```

Initialize Raphael:

```
var paper = new Raphael("someID");
```

See this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JayKandari/1gh5s6ca/